# Interesting sum

Tags: calculus

Hi could you demostrated that
$$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{m+1} \log (\Gamma (m+1))=\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)$$ and
$$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \log (\Gamma (m+1))=\log \left((2 \pi )^{3/4} A\right)-\frac{3}{4}$$
I know this series are divergent.

Comment: If they are divergent, then what do the equations mean? and what is $A$?

Comment: Hi A is glassier constant i think ist possible check numerecally using euler.boole sum formula.

Comment: Do you mean the Glaisher constant, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher–Kinkelin_constant ? I'm not sure how you check a divergent series numerically, but then I don't know the Euler-Boole sum formula.

Comment: I am hesitant to downvote the question. @capea, can you clarify what you mean by "equality" if you know both series are divergent? Because if you *know* they are divergent, writing an equality up there doesn't work in the classical sense.

Comment: HI you can see http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40391116?uid=3737952&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102653915233

Comment: @capea You need to pay to see the article about your question, so please explain clearly your problem so everyone can understand.

Comment: I think the first sum is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272083/kind-of-counter-intuitive-sum-of-log-gamma

Answer (score 1):

The sum can have the following integral representation

> $$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{m+1} \log (\Gamma (m+1))=-\frac{1}{4}\,\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {u\ln  \left( u \right)+\ln  \left( u
>  \right) -2\,u+2}{\ln  \left( u \right)  \left( {u}^{2}-1 \right) }}{d
> u}-\frac{\gamma}{4}\sim -.1128956763. $$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

Comment: In what sense are those three expressions equal? If that integral converges, how does it represent the divergent sum? If the integral doesn't converge, how does it equal that decimal?